# socket io on sails js as API and node+react as Frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, redux

I have an API build using [sailsjs](http://sailsjs.com) and a react redux attach to a nodejs backend, and i am trying to implement socket.io for a realtime communication, how does this work?

is it

1. socket.io client on the react side that connects to a socket.io server on its nodejs backend that connects to a socket.io server on the API
2. socket.io client on the react side and on its nodejs backend that connects to a socket.io server on the API

i have tried looking around for some answers, but none seems to meet my requirements.

to try things out, i put the `hello` endpoint on my API, using [the sailsjs realtime documentation](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/realtime), but when i do a `sails lift` i got this error `Could not fetch session, since connecting socket has no cookie (is this a cross-origin socket?)` i figure that i need to pass an auth code inside the `request headers Authorization` property.

Assuming i went for my #1 question, and by using [redux-socket.io](https://github.com/itaylor/redux-socket.io),

In my redux middleware i created a `socketMiddleware`

```
import createSocketIoMiddleware from 'redux-socket.io'
import io from 'socket.io-client'

import config from '../../../config'

const socket = io(config.host)

export default function socketMiddleware() {
  return createSocketIoMiddleware(
    socket,
    () => next => (action) => {
      const { nextAction, shuttle, ...rest } = action

      if (!shuttle) {
        return next(action)
      }

      const { socket_url: shuttleUrl = '' } = config

      const apiParams = {
        data: shuttle,
        shuttleUrl,
      }

      const nextParams = {
        ...rest,
        promise: api => api.post(apiParams),
        nextAction,
      }

      return next(nextParams)
    },
  )
}
```

and in my redux store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import createSocketIoMiddleware from 'redux-socket.io'

...

import rootReducers from '../reducer'


import socketMiddleware from '../middleware/socketMiddleware'
import promiseMiddleware from '../middleware/promiseMiddleware'
...

import config from '../../../config'

export default function configStore(initialState) {
  const socket = socketMiddleware()
  ...
  const promise = promiseMiddleware(new ApiCall())

  const middleware = [
    applyMiddleware(socket),
    ...
    applyMiddleware(promise),
  ]

  if (config.env !== 'production') {
    middleware.push(DevTools.instrument())
  }

  const createStoreWithMiddleware = compose(...middleware)
  const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(createStore)(rootReducers, initialState)

  ...

  return store
}
```

in my `promiseMiddleware`

```
export default function promiseMiddleware(api) {
  return () => next => (action) => {
    const { nextAction, promise, type, ...rest } = action

    if (!promise) {
      return next(action)
    }

    const [REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILURE] = type

    next({ ...rest, type: REQUEST })

    function success(res) {
      next({ ...rest, payload: res, type: SUCCESS })
      if (nextAction) {
        nextAction(res)
      }
    }

    function error(err) {
      next({ ...rest, payload: err, type: FAILURE })
      if (nextAction) {
        nextAction({}, err)
      }
    }

    return promise(api)
      .then(success, error)
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error('ERROR ON THE MIDDLEWARE: ', REQUEST, err) // eslint-disable-line no-console
        next({ ...rest, payload: err, type: FAILURE })
      })
  }
}
```

my `ApiCall`

```
/* eslint-disable camelcase */

import superagent from 'superagent'

...

const methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch', 'del']

export default class ApiCall {
  constructor() {
    methods.forEach(method =>
      this[method] = ({ params, data, shuttleUrl, savePath, mediaType, files } = {}) =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const request = superagent[method](shuttleUrl)

          if (params) {
            request.query(params)
          }

          ...

          if (data) {
            request.send(data)
          }

          request.end((err, { body } = {}) => err ? reject(body || err) : resolve(body))
        },
    ))
  }
}
```

All this relation between the middlewares and the store works well on regular http api call. My question is, am i on the right path? if i am, then what should i write on this reactjs server part to communicate with the api socket? should i also use [socket.io-client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add [sails.io.js](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js) at your node server. Sails socket behavior it's quite tricky. Since, it's not using `on` method to listen the event.

Create sails endpoint which handle socket request. The documentation is [here](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/sails-sockets). The documentation is such a pain in the ass, but please bear with it.

On your node server. You can use it like

```
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client'
import sailsIOClient from 'sails.io.js'

const ioClient = sailsIOClient(socketIOClient)
ioClient.sails.url = "YOUR SOCKET SERVER URL"

ioClient.socket.get("SAILS ENDPOINT WHICH HANDLE SOCKET", function(data) {
  console.log('Socket Data', data);
})
```